# How to filter database records by month and year if they have LocalDate attribute inside?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Workday` object in my database. I would like to display the amount of hours (`hoursWorked`) an employee had worked per particular day on a Spring web app.

In order to do this, I need to filter the `Workdays` by date and that is month and year only. Then display them on kind of a calendar for the specific period chosen (i.e. 2018-01).

What is the best practice to do this? Have 2 dropdown lists on the web app. First to choose a month, second for a year. Then convert both strings to LocalDate? I'm quiet new to Spring and couldn't find a proper solution.

```
public class Workday {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private Integer hoursWorked;
private Integer advancePayment;
private LocalDate date;

@ManyToOne
private Employee employee;
```

### ---------------

So, this might be a little hard. I do have 4 HTML views:

- Main
- Employees
- specificEmployee
- newEmployee

I do have an EmployeeController that handles rendering all the views as well as handling the new Employee creation.

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

private final EmployeeService employeeService;
private final WorkdayService workdayService;

public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService, WorkdayService workdayService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
    this.workdayService = workdayService;
}

//Renders Employees view. There's a list of employees with some details.
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public String showEmployees(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("employees", employeeService.getEmployees());

    return "employees";
}

//Renders a specific Employee view that contains a specific Employee information. 
//Like name, address etc. There's also a list of hours worked a day that I want to filter.
//This view includes the <input type="month"> to actually get the yyyy-mm date required for filtering.

@RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
public String showSpecificEmployee(@PathVariable String id, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findEmployeeById(new Long(id)));
//Newly created date command object to retrieve the date String from the form
    model.addAttribute("date", new DateCommand());

    return "specificEmployee";
}

//A method rendering the new Employee forms and binding that Employee command object to it.
@GetMapping
@RequestMapping("/new_employee")
public String newEmployee(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("employee", new EmployeeCommand());

    return "newEmployee";
}

//Saving the Employee command object with forms information to the database and rendering the specific employee view with the new employee.
@PostMapping
@RequestMapping("employee")
public String saveOrEdit(@ModelAttribute EmployeeCommand commandObject){

    EmployeeCommand savedCommand = employeeService.saveEmployeeCommand(commandObject);

    return "redirect:/employee/" + savedCommand.getId();
}

//New employee view is also used for editing employees.
@GetMapping
@RequestMapping("employee/{id}/edit")
public String editEmployee(@PathVariable String id, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.findCommandById(new Long(id)));

    return  "newEmployee";
}

//A method used for deleting employees. Returns employees view.
@GetMapping
@RequestMapping("employee/{id}/delete")
public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable String id, Model model){

    employeeService.deleteEmployee(new Long(id));
    model.addAttribute("employees", employeeService.getEmployees());

    return "employees";
}

//That's the one I need to figure out. Since the Date I want to get is on the specificEmployee view,  I completly do not know what to return and what @RequestMapping to use.
@PostMapping
@RequestMapping("/employee/{id}")
public String updateWorkmonth(@ModelAttribute String date){

    String data = date;
    System.out.println(data);

    return "redirect://employee/{id}";
}
```

}

And the HTML form code. Yet again I do not know where to th:action should direct to.

```
<form th:object="${date}" th:action="@{}">
         Choose a month:
         <input type="month" th:field="*{actualDate}">
         <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you need anything else, feel free to ask. I may provide a github repo as well.

Comment: To represent the entire month, Java provides the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you would want something where the user can input a start date and an end date. Those two dates will then be passed down to your controller.

In your get request you could do something like /employees?startDate=20180212&endDate=20180214

Then for your Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public String showEmployees(Model model, @RequestParam(value="startDate") String startDate, @RequestParam(value="endDate") String endDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDD");
    Date start = sdf.parse(startDate);
    Date end = sdf.parse(endDate);
    model.addAttribute("employees", employeeService.getEmployees(start, end));

    return "employees";
}
```

Then have logic to test to see if startDate and/or endDate are null before the parse and handle accordingly.

Then you can create a Spring query such as

```
List<Workday> findByDateBetween(Date date1, Date date2);
```

This will return a list of workdays that fall between the two dates.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Do I need to create a separate model object for retrieving that String?
Something like
    public class Date{

   String description;
   Long id;
}

Comment: Please post your controller on how you are sending the data from the client to the server, and any other services, repositories that you are using to retrieve the data.

Comment: Edited. Check the original post.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).